# Why MongoDB adding extra slash to path?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Good evening for everyone, I have some trouble with saving my url to mongodb database as string. Because mongo adding extra slash to every part of url. Like this:
**"localhost:3333\uploads\Untitled1.cpp"**
but in my console log I have normal result(look at the terminal in the screenshot). Whyy? Please, help

```
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) =>{
        cb(null, '/uploads')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})

let upload = multer({ storage: storage })
let type = upload.single('myFile');

app.post('/upload', type, (req, res) => {
    const url = `http://localhost:3333${req.file.path}`;
    const image = {
        name: req.file.originalname,
        url: url
    }
    console.log(image.url)
    const newImage = new Image(image);
    newImage.save()
        .then (res.json('Картинку додано'))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json(err));
});
```

[image: console.log result in terminal]

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using a Windows operating system which uses back slashes '\' for paths in its filesystem. The web (and Linux-based operating systems) use forward slashes '/' for paths. Therefore ${req.file.path}, which I'm guessing is referencing a file on your computer, is returning a path including back slashes.

You can use `String.replace()` with a regular expression to replace the back slashes with forward slashes:

```
let webPath = req.file.path.replace(/\\/g,'/'))
const url = `http://localhost:3333${webPath}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. What you need to do is when you are posting/saving your file into db there you need to use replace function and then your path will be saved with forward slash into your DB.

Here is the snippet:

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
  const file = new Cluster1({
    filePath: req.file.path.replace(/\\/g, '/'),
    name: req.file.originalname
  });
  file.save()
```

You can see how I am using the replace fucntion to avoid `\\` or `\`